# What is meaning of error 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript

I have created a small web site, where I am showing some data, which I get from an API (JSON data type). In my console I am getting these two errors:

1) GET http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/u-WUoqrET9fUeobQW7jkRRJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2 404 (Not Found)

error 1) is in my code pointing to this line of code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

2) GET http://localhost/[object%20Event] 404 (Not Found)

and error 2) is in my code pointing on this line of code:

```
function getData(url){
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: url
    });
}
```

Any idea what these errors mean? These particular errors have no effect on the site; the site is still working and showing all data.

Comment: The error says exactly what it means: **(Not Found)**.  The server has no idea what your URL means.

Comment: If you can't find your car keys in the morning, then they're 404...

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax post - 404 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378958/jquery-ajax-post-404-error)

Comment: The second error means that the variable `url` in your "getData" function isn't what you think it is; it's an event object and not a URL string.

Comment: I get the same error when I use jQuery animate function. This did not happen yesterday.

Answer (score 5):

The 404 code means that the server was unable to locate the files you were looking for via GET request.

You might try adding the text/javascript type to your  tags, as the examples for google maps api do.

ie:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

As far as the second problem you encountered, it looks like the url you passed into the getData() function was invalid.

Comment: just wondering what you mean by adding google maps api in tags? Has he not done that already?

Comment: I made a mistake and mixed 1) and 2) in my rush to answer the question.  He does use the script tags, but he forgot to include the text/javascript type.

Comment: ah ok, cheers for that. Also, no need to be rushing with your answer, you will get your points, better to provide info as clearly as possible, in order to help the whole community :-)

Comment: will definitely do from now on

Comment: NOTE: 404 does not guarentee the file doesn't exist on the server. The server might not want to disclose the file, and send a 404

Answer (score 0):

ajax is asynchronous request means that you cant return it when it is in progress so if you want return any thing from ajax you must call it's events like `success` and `error`.so your code must like below:

```
function getData(url){  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: url,

        success: function(data){
          return data;
        },

        error: function(data){
          console.log(data.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```