# URLLIB request code reading issue. Cannot read error code 404

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, urllib

I am trying to read the url code using URLLIB. Here is my code:

```
import urllib

url = "https://www.facebook.com/fads0000fass"

r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
p = r.code

if(p == "HTTP Error 404: Not Found" ):
        print("hello")
else:
        print("null")
```

The url I am using will show error code 404 but I am not able to read it.
I also tried `if(p == 404)` but I get the same issue.
I Can read other codes i.e. 200, 201 etc.

Can you please help me fix it?

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gd.py", line 7, in <module>
    r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658375/what-is-meaning-of-error-404-not-found

Comment: Pick a python version. Urllib varies from 2 to 3.

Comment: @Sushanth No sorry. it doesnt

Comment: @SamMorgan I am not sure but i think its urllib2. But the basic features are same I guess. Also, I can make changes according to the answer if this is the issue

Comment: @bitch_ctrl What I meant was: You have multiple Python tags here. urllib varies from Python 2 to Python 3, and for anyone to give you a useful answer, they'll need to know what environment you're running in.

**Side note:** I'd highly recommend using the requests library for HTTP, it's sort of become the unofficial standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that's what you're asking.

```
import urllib.request

url = "https://www.facebook.com/fads0000fass"

try:
    r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    p = r.code
except urllib.error.HTTPError:
    print("hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to reach your if statement, your code needs exception handling. An exception is being raised when you call `urlopen` on line 7. See the first step of your traceback.

```
File "gd.py", line 7, in <module>
  r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

The exception happens here, which causes your code to exit, so further statements aren't evaluated. To get past this, you must [handle the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

```py
import urllib.request

url = "https://www.facebook.com/fads0000fass"

try:
    r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    # More useful
    # print(f"{e.code}: {e.reason}\n\n{e.headers}")
    if e.code in [404]:
        print("hello")
    else:
        print("null")
```

---

Going beyond this, if you want something more like your original logic, I'd recommend using the [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library. I'd actually recommend using requests for all of your HTTP needs whenever possible, it's exceptionally good.

```py
import requests

r = requests.get(url)
p = r.status_code

if r.status_code == 404:
    print("hello")
else:
    print("null")
```