# Python Pandas how to get f-string to work in an url

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting an error of `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found.` I feel like f-string should work for the url but it is not how would I fix this?

```
import pandas as pd

stockslist = ['f','goog', 'aapl']
for s in stockslist:
    url = f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{s}/'
    print(url)
    tablelist = pd.read_html(url, flavor='html5lib')
    df = pd.concat(tablelist[:2])
    print(df)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URLLIB request code reading issue. Cannot read error code 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61975308/urllib-request-code-reading-issue-cannot-read-error-code-404)

Comment: @ShaneS would you like to try out with `yfinance`? I've been working the same way as yours except I'm using yfinance. And what output are you seeking?

Answer (score 3):

you have to parse html first then read it

try it:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    stockslist = ['f','goog', 'aapl']
    for s in stockslist:
        print(s)
        url = f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{s}/'
        html = requests.get(url).content
        tablelist = pd.read_html(html, flavor='html5lib')
        df = pd.concat(tablelist[:2])
        print(df)
```

Comment: You solution it is close to fully working. The df is returning "0  Will be right back...  Thank you for your pati..." so I thought to add `import time` and just after `html = requests...` I added  `time.sleep(5)`.  but this still is not returning the expected tables. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: debug html variable and trace html content ,already disabled current url by owner , <body>
  <!-- status code : 404 -->
  <!-- Not Found on Server -->
  <table>